# React calling methods in different conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

I'm beginner on react and i've written the code below:

```
class Note extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {editing: false};

        this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
        this.save = this.save.bind(this);

   }

   edit() {
       // alert('edit');
       this.setState({editing: !this.state.editing});
   }

   save() {
       this.props.onChange(this.refs.newVal.value, this.props.id);
       this.setState({editing: !this.state.editing});
       // console.log('save is over');
   }

   renderForm() {
       return (
           <div className="note">
               <textarea ref="newVal"></textarea>
               <button onClick={this.save}>SAVE</button>
           </div>
       );
   }

   renderDisplay() {
       return (
           <div className="note">
               <p>{this.props.children}</p>
               <span>
                         <button onClick={this.edit}>EDIT</button>
                        <button onClick={this.remove}>X</button>
               </span>
           </div>
       );
   }

   render() {
       console.log(this.state.editing);
       return (this.state.editing) ? this.renderForm()
           : this.renderDisplay()

   }
}

class Board extends React.Component {

   constructor(props){
       super(props);

       this.state = {
           notes: []
       };

       this.update = this.update.bind(this);
       this.eachNote = this.eachNote.bind(this);
       this.add = this.add.bind(this);
   }

   nextId() {
       this.uniqeId = this.uniqeId || 0;
       return this.uniqeId++;
   }

   add(text) {
       let notes = [
           ...this.state.notes,
           {
               id: this.nextId(),
               note: text
           }
       ];

       this.setState({notes});
   }

   update(newText, id) {
       let notes = this.state.notes.map(
           note => (note.id !== id) ?
               note :
               {
                   id: id,
                   note: newText
               }
       );
       this.setState({notes})
   }

    eachNote(note) {
       return (<Note key={note.id}
                     id={note.id}
                     onChange={this.update}>

           {note.note}
       </Note>)
   }

   render() {
       return (<div className='board'>
           {this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}
           <button onClick={() => this.add()}>+</button>
       </div>)
   } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<Board />,
   document.getElementById('root'));
```

In render(), onClick event has a function, that is, if used in this way: **{this.add}** the following error is created:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, _targetInst, nativeEvent, type, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted, view, detail, ...})

Why? while in the eachNote() method this command is used:

> onChange={this.update}

And there was no error.

Someone can tell me the reason? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the add function you are taking an argument text and setting it in the state so when you call `onClick={() => this.add()}`, you are not passing any argument to add function and hence in its definition `text` is undefned and hence `state note` is set as undefined.

However if you directly call it like `onClick={this.add}` , the `add` function receives the `event` object as a parameter and hence it sets `state note` to be an event object which you are using to `render`

Comment: How can I use this: onClick={this.add}. what changes should I make?

Comment: If you want to pass a text value to the add function then, `onClick={this.add}` won't directly work. You need to bind a value to the function as well so you can either do `onClick={this.add.bind(this, text)}` or `onClick={() => this.add(text)}`

Answer (score 1):

`onClick={this.add}` will pass the click event to `this.add`.

So what you need to do is either:

`onClick={e => this.add('some text')}` or similar.

If you want to `onClick={this.add}` you have to ensure that your add method is: `add(event) { ... }` instead.

Comment: I edited my code and i added save() method in the Note class, In the renderForm() method i used onClick={this.save} and there was no error but in the Board class and render method this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Note />` component does not contain a `render()` method to return anything. Add a `render()` method and return something.

```js
class Note extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {editing: false};

        this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);

   }

   edit() {
       // alert('edit');
       this.setState({editing: !this.state.editing});
   }
   
   render() {
     return (
       <div>Render something</div>
     )
   }
}

class Board extends React.Component {

   constructor(props){
       super(props);

       this.state = {
           notes: []
       };

       this.update = this.update.bind(this);
       this.eachNote = this.eachNote.bind(this);
       this.add = this.add.bind(this);
   }

   nextId() {
       this.uniqeId = this.uniqeId || 0;
       return this.uniqeId++;
   }

   add(text) {
       let notes = [
           ...this.state.notes,
           {
               id: this.nextId(),
               note: text
           }
       ];

       this.setState({notes});
   }

   update(newText, id) {
       let notes = this.state.notes.map(
           note => (note.id !== id) ?
               note :
               {
                   id: id,
                   note: newText
               }
       );
       this.setState({notes})
   }

    eachNote(note) {
       return (<Note key={note.id}
                     id={note.id}
                     onChange={this.update}>

           {note.note}
       </Note>)
   }

   render() {
       return (<div className='board'>
           {this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}
           <button onClick={() => this.add()}>+</button>
       </div>)
   } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<Board />,
   document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```